# removing chars from a string - C

Tags: c

Suppose I have a `char* word = "abaradasaddragfavvdavgasbga00rarcrawabr0ac0ra0ra0vra0"`
and I want to remove all the `'0' chars` from the `word`, in place, without using extra-memory or `memmove`. How could I do it?
So the output would be: `"abaradasaddragfavvdavgasbgararcrawabracraravra"`
** What I have tried **:

```
void removeZeros( char* word) {

   int size = strlen( word );
   int i;
   for( i = 0; i < size; i++ ){
         if( word[i] == '0' ){
             word[ i ]  = word[ i + 1 ];
             i++;
         }
   }
}
```

*** Rules **:

- should be done in place
- should not call any built-in function like `memmove` or `remove`
- should not use extra-memory
- should not assign it to another variable

Comment: @willglynn That's not a homework question, I was in an interview and they asked to do so without `memmove`, which was the only way I knew.

Comment: Well, if you know how to do it with `memmove()`, what's to stop you from doing it with your own implementation of `memmove()`?

Comment: The Microsoft manager which I was interviewing with ... he asked to do it in place, with no helper function call, with no extra memory nor assigning it to another variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function to remove spaces from string/char array in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084236/function-to-remove-spaces-from-string-char-array-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// this assumes your variable word is really a cstr and is NULL terminated
// also, it assumes that it's not in read only memory space like your small
// example shows but is actually in-place writeable
char* write_position = word;
char* scan_position = word;
for( ; *scan_position != '\0'; scan_position++ ) {
  if( *scan_position == '0' ) continue;
  *(write_position++) = *scan_position;
}
*write_position = '\0';
```

Comment: Jason, almost there ... but it can't use an extra variable or pointer ( You use `char * scan_position` ).

Comment: The code in your post includes two integer variables. Are local variables allowed or not?

Comment: The `integer` variables are of course allowed. The creating a copy of `char* word`, assigning it to a pointer or another variable, using a function to remove the `'0'` `char` is not.

Comment: @philippe I think that your interviewer didn't want you to allocate another string. You need local variables to track your position, whether they're pointers (which, IMHO is the easiest as demonstrated above), or offsets, it needs to be tracked. If my interviewer told me I'd done this incorrect with the above code because of the `scan_position` variable, I'd laugh and turn down the job. Of course, you could always simply advance the `word` variable in exactly the same way, but I don't know the rest of the context and wouldn't want to update a pointer that I don't know where it came from.

Comment: @philippe You are not understanding C. I did not create any copies of this string or memory at all. It is the exact same memory cost plus 64 bits on a 32-bit processor or 128 bits on a 64-bit processor.

Comment: I saw your solution, it's correct ... you just did it in another way I was expecting. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char word[] = "abaradasaddragfavvdavgasbga00rarcrawabr0ac0ra0ra0vra0";

    int size = strlen( word ) + 1;

    std::remove(word, (sizeof(char) * size) + word, '0');
    std::cout << word;

}
```

Comment: Caesar, thanks for your answer, but it shouldn't be calling another function to remove the `'0'` for me.

Comment: @philippe You should state that in the original post.

Comment: I think the question is now only about C...

Comment: @I've updated my question. I was caught off guard in this question too, because I always used `memmove` if it was `C` and `remove` if it was `C++`.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over the string from start to end.  For each 0 you find, increment an integer called offset, say.  For every non-0 character, move it down by the current value of offset.  Make sure to put a null byte on the end.

Comment: Like I did in my answer?